# python pip is not recognized?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-7, pip

When I try to use pip in command prompt I get the following error message: pip is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I checked several posts I think I may have deleted something I shouldn't have in my registry. I had to delete references to python in the registry to get EDIT with IDLE back in my context menu.(which worked)

But now I can't use pip. per another post here is the results of...

```
C:\Python32>echo %PATH%
C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program
Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common F
iles\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\Sys
tem32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\AT
I Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\9
0\Tools\binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\
Java\jre6\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Calibre2\;C:\Python32;C:\Python32\Lib;C:\Py
thon32\DLLs;C:\Python32\Lib\lib-tk;C:\Python32;C:\Python32\scripts;
```

as you can see at the end pip is in the correct path.
when I try running the cmd prompt from the scripts folder and using...
pip.exe import (modulename) it takes some time then does nothing giving me another blank prompt with no output. I am using python 3.2 with pygame I need pytmx.

Comment: What exactly are you entering? Just "pip" and nothing else?

Comment: pip install pytmx from the scripts directory if I run cmd from start menu I still get pip is not recognized

Answer (score 2):

The path environment variable expects to contain only directory names. The last entry there, `C:\Python32\scripts\pip`, looks like a directory name plus the name of an executable inside that directory (minus the ".exe" extension). Try adding just `C:\Python32\scripts` to your path.

Comment: Okay I did that it just does nothing now. Command seems to execute, but no output in cmd.

Answer (score 0):

As @Kevin said, the `PATH` variable should contain only directories and not file names.

```
SET PATH=PATH;C:\Python32\scripts
```

If you don't want to use the entire `C:\Python32\scripts` in the path

use

```
doskey pip=C:\Python32\scripts\pip $
```

to set an alias

Comment: can you clarify what is "doskey pip=C:\Python32\scripts\pip $"?

Comment: it creates an alias in windows, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_%28command%29

Comment: It still doesn't do anything. No matter what I do I get nothing if I run pip install command. no error message no package nothing.

Comment: run `cmd` as an administrator, and make sure that pip is the task manager, something should be printed to the console

Comment: If this answer was helpful please accept an answer or at least vote up

Comment: okay I ran cmd as administrator typed in pip install pytmx nothing used pip.exe install pytmx still nothing. How do I make sure that "pip is the task manager"? as soon as I get a workable answer I'll upvote everybody, and accept whichever answer works.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. I installed anaconda then installed python 3.4 I can now install all the relevant packages with pip using version 3.4. I don't know why this worked but it fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add C:\Users\\Anaconda3\Scripts\ to your PATH
or
Open anaconda from the start menu. It opens a terminal and from there you can use pip.